# VUEX - array.PUSH no funciona con objetos

Tags: javascript, array, vuex, push

He hecho una llamada a la api para obtener unos datos. La action/funcion que se encarga de ésto es `cargarBBDD`.

EL caso es que hace la llamada correctamente y trae los datos, pero cuando intento meterlos en un array `arrayArticulos`, no mete nada, es como si el push no estuviera funcionando.

En la función/action he hecho un `console.log(dataDB[id])`, y efectivamente ahí está el objeto que traigo de la BBDD (son 4 objetos en total) pero en `console.log("articulos" + arrayArticulos)` muestra:
`articulos,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Y éste error tambien lo muestra, ya que estoy intentando acceder a la propiedad 'name':
`Home.vue?a74f:7 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')`

Editado: No podía acceder a la propiedad 'name' ya que el primer elemento del array arrayArticulos era null. Ésto se debía a un error desde la BBDD.

**index.js**

```
export default createStore({

state: {
 categoriaArticulos: [
   "lamina", "bolso"
 ],
 articulos: [],
 id: '',
 carrito: {},
 message:'Test'
},


mutations: {
 obtenerId(state, payload){
   state.id=payload
 },
 setAgregarCarrito(state, payload){
   state.carrito[payload.id] = { ...payload }
   console.log(state.carrito)
 },
 cargarBBDD(state, payload){
   state.articulos=payload
 }
},


actions:{
 obtenerId({commit}, id){
   commit('obtenerId', id)
 },

 setAgregarCarrito({commit, state}, articulo){
   state.carrito.hasOwnProperty(articulo.id) 
   ? articulo.cantidad = state.carrito[articulo.id].cantidad + 1
   : articulo.cantidad = 1 
   commit('setAgregarCarrito', articulo)
 
 },

 async cargarBBDD({commit}){
   try{
     const res = await fetch('https://tienda-vue-48a31-default-rtdb.europe- 
     west1.firebasedatabase.app/articulos.json')
     const dataDB = await res.json()
     
     const arrayArticulos = []
     for (let id in dataDB){
       console.log(dataDB[id])
       arrayArticulos.push(dataDB[id])
       console.log("articulos" + arrayArticulos)
     }
     console.log("articulos" + arrayArticulos)
     commit('cargarBBDD', arrayArticulos)

   }catch(err){
     console.log(err)
   }
 }
},


getters: {
 obtenerArticulosPorCategoria: (state) => (id) => {
   return state.articulos.filter(art=> art.categoria==id)
 },

 obtenerArticuloPorId(state){
   const articulo=state.articulos.find(art=> art.id===state.id)
   console.log(articulo)
   return articulo
 }

},

})
```

**home.js**

````
<div class="home">
 <header>
 LA ILUSTRACIÓN FUERA DEL LIBRO
 <div class="tiendabutton"><router-link to="/tiendashop">Tienda/Shop</router-link></div>
 
 <pre>{{articulos}}</pre>

 <div v-for="item in articulos" :key="item.name">
   <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
 </div>
 
</header>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapState} from 'vuex'

export default {
name: 'Home',
components: {
},
computed: {
 ...mapState(['articulos'])
},
created(){
 this.$store.dispatch("cargarBBDD")
}
}
</script>```
````

Comment: Al hacer console log estas concatenando a un texto, por eso se te presenta de esa forma, debes separarlo con una coma, cambia el const de arrayArticulos por let; luego muestranos el resultado de dataDB[i] para ayudarte con la propiedad name.

Comment: porque, si esto es un store, estas modificando los datos en las actions????? si vas a modificar un dato, debe ser en las mutations, que para eso estan....

Comment: @JonathanOrta Efectivamente el array tenía datos, no estaba usando el console.log correctamente. Veo que me devuelve un array con todos los objetos que requiero, pero en la primera posición devuelve `null`, no hay objeto. Imagino que esa es la razón por la que no está accediendo correctamente a las propiedades. He añadido a mi pregunta el componente. Tienes idea de porqué está agregando un null en primera posición? Espero haberme explicado, gracias

Comment: @gbianchi Estoy aprendiendo VUEX actualmente. El profe del curso lo hace así. De todas formas  realmente el state se está modificando en las mutations no? No entiendo a que te refieres la verdad.

Comment: Bueno.. pues tu profesor lo esta haciendo mal.. el state solo se modifica en las mutations.. de la documentacion: "The only way to actually change state in a Vuex store is by committing a mutation" [aca](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#commit-with-payload)

Comment: Es mas.. preguntale a tu profesor, si puede modificar el state dentro de una action, entonces cual es la diferencia entre una action y una mutation...